# Customizable GUI controls in separate project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection

A winclient is using GUI controls (BaseForm, BaseTextBox, BaseComboBox) from a separate GUI project which is used in other projects as well

These controls change backgroundcolor to yellow-ish when they are focused and retains their old backgroundcolor when focus leaves. (onEnter and OnLeave events)

Now, this winclient will let the users choose their own focus color. I know I can directly set the "FocusColor" property on all the controls but that's not what i want (there's a lot of controls)

What's the best approach? I thought maybe I could inject some kind of "CustomColorProvider" into the controls and rewrite the GUI project to fetch the focuscolor from a "StandardColorProvider". But I don't exactly how these controls should get their "CustomColorProvider" injected. (I'm not so experienced with DI) The controls are added via the designer and the creation of controls is by auto-generated code "partial designer class"

Or maybe I should just write new controls in this specific winclient which inherits from the GUI project and then override the methods where the focuscolor is set?

I have access and allowed to modify both the winclient and the GUI project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, I would use the Decorator pattern, passing a different concrete decorator depending on how you want to extend the control. You can find an example [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx#_self1).

EDIT:

Declare an interface **IControlExtender**

```
public interface IControlExtender
{
    Color BackColor { get; }
    Color HighlightColor { get; }
}
```

Create a default implementation

```
class DefaultExtender : IControlExtender
{
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get { return Color.Yellow; }
    }

    public Color HighlightColor
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }
}
```

Add a property to your GUI control

```
IControlExtender _extender = new DefaultExtender();
public IControlExtender Extender
{
    get { return _extender; }
    set
    {
        if ((value != null) && (value != _extender))
        {
            _extender = value;
            RefreshControl();
        }
    }
}

void RefreshControl()
{
    this.BackColor = Extender.BackColor;
}
```

Create any new implementations, such as

```
class CustomExtender:IControlExtender
{
    public Color BackColor
    {
        get { return Color.Green; }
    }

    public Color HighlightColor
    {
        get { return Color.Pink; }
    }
}
```

And override the default as you need

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    control1.Extender = new CustomExtender();
}
```

Comment: thanks! but what if want to do it the DI way, and not subclassing? have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your GUI controls add an handler for the OnEnter and OnLeave event, I will try to extend that method with a new one accepting another parameter, your desidered color. Then save that color globally and use it in the OnEnter method.

Comment: so you are suggesting subclassing the GUI controls and override?

Comment: Well, no. You say that you are allowed to modify the GUI project. If you show the code where the GUI add the handler to OnEnter we can extend that method with an overload accepting the color to use for background. However this has nothing to do with DI.

Comment: well, the Enter and Leave handlers are added in the constructor of the class. and the methods which fire on enter and leave does nothing else than setting the backcolor.

Comment: What prevents you to add another constructor then? Suppose you have GUIControl c = new GUIControl(pos, size);. Add a new constructor with backcolor as parameter like GUIControl c = new GUIControl(pos, size, backcolor). Save the passed color and change the OnEnter method to use this color instead of the yellow-ish fixed one.